# Ruby on Rails: How to show all products by current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, backend

In my application, I have multiple users and each user is entitled to make unique list(s) for oneself. In the specific list created, contains many products. Now, I'm trying to make a page for the current user to display all the products regardless of which list they belong. How can I implement this? These are currently my models.

**user.rb**

```
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
           :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_many :grocery_lists, dependent: :destroy
```

**grocery_list.rb**

```
  belongs_to :user
    has_many :grocery_list_products, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :products, through: :grocery_list_products
```

**grocery_list_product.rb**

```
  belongs_to :grocery_list
  belongs_to :product
```

**product.rb**

```
    has_many :grocery_list_products, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :grocery_lists, through: :grocery_list_products
```

Comment: Please post an example of what you would like the final output to be and include a list of the things that you have attempted so far while trying to solve this and an explanation of why those things did not work.

Comment: In your controller, you can find the user by the params. Then compare to the `current_user` if they match, show the current user's stuff and if they don't show the selected users stuff or if you want it private, return an error

Comment: `Product.joins(:grocery_lists).where(grocery_lists: {user_id: current_user.id}).distinct` should work